# Admin panel for user token management

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I want to create custom admin panel.

In admin panel having two main functionality.
`user management`
and 
`token management`

I completed all things but I shrugged in token management.

when admin user adding new user so it will generate token.
and users_list view i can see all fields with token.

please suggest me some idea how to do

Comment: I want to generate token and shown to admin.py  in djangobamdin

Comment: Have you visited the docs about how to customize the admin for your needs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/